# background-size: contain; резиновый height

Tags: html, css

Имеется картинка 2500 х 862, которую я хочу выставить в качестве background(a) одного из блоков. Картинка должна так же адаптироваться при уменьшении размера экрана внутри блока. Я воспользовался свойством **background-size: contain;** который не плохо подошел, почти как в boosttrap class img-response, только для картинок.
    Но есть одно но, при уменьшении экрана ширина уменьшается(картинка адаптируется) = уменьшается так же и высота картинки(**но не блока!**) и получается дырка в div. Как я понял  height не резиновый, но я не могу его не прописать т.к без этого вообще div исчезает. Что мне предпринять, что бы heigth двигался на равне с изменением размеров картинки а не оставался прежним 635px?

```
.bot{
    height: 635px;
    background-image: url(../img/bottom.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: попробуйте указать height в vw а не в px.. не лучшее решение, но в принципе должно работать

Comment: @Darth, спасибо, это решает проблему в какойто степени)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эластичное фоновое изображение можно сделать с применением 
    padding-top: 56.25%
либо padding-bottom: 56.25%;

например, как вот здесь.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdoxgJ

Подробно об адаптивных фоновых изображениях можно прочитать тут - http://habrahabr.ru/post/157817/

Answer (score 1):

в данном случае лучше использывать img а не background-image. или же нужно будет регулировать высоту блока с помощью js. Ответ на ваш вопрос по [ссылке](http://codepen.io/infomanyak/pen/waBaNZ)

код:
html

```
<div class="bot">
<img src="http://noxblog.ru/uploads/posts/2012-02/1329243992_guitar-and-leads_1600_mini.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

css

```
img{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.bot{background: #ccc;
    max-height: 600px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, понятно что лучше <img использовать, но там такое дело, что на этот img нужно будет поверх текст и картинки ложить, что для меня вызовет путанницу несусветную. Абсолютное позиционирование блоков по верх картинок и пошло поехало, пробовал - запутался.

Answer (score 1):

Может, вам нужен просто `background-size: cover;`? Он как `contain`, только не оставляет нигде дырок (вместо этого обрезает невлезающую картинку).

Comment: пробовал) на крайний случай можно, а так он картинку перекрывает...

Comment: А, я не обратил внимание на «heigth двигался», тогда да, не пойдёт, наверно надо javascript

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте:

```
backgrounnd-size: cover;
```